# how to fix a scoreboard (rewritten)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I get my scoreboard to add +1 point at a time, instead of +10?

JavaScript (used intervals cause it was the only thing that worked.):

```js
let placar = setInterval(updated);
let pontuacao = 0;

function updated() {
  var pontos = document.getElementById('score');
  pontos.innerHTML = "score: " + pontuacao++;
  clearInterval(placar);
}

const loopGame = setInterval(() => {

  const pipePosition = pipe.offsetLeft;
  const marioPosition = +window
    .getComputedStyle(mario)
    .bottom.replace("px", "")

  if (pipePosition <= 120 && pipePosition > 0 && marioPosition < 80) {
    pipe.style.animation = "none";
    pipe.style.left = `${pipePosition}px`;

    mario.style.animation = "none";
    mario.style.bottom = `${marioPosition}px`;

    mario.src = "./images/mario-game-over.png";
    mario.style.width = "75px";
    mario.style.marginLeft = "45px";

    clearInterval(loopGame);

  } else if (pipePosition <= 0 && marioPosition >= 0) {

    updated();

  };

}, 10);
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div id="score"></div>
</div>
```

link to the page:

https://ana-luiza-sampaio.github.io/jogo_mario_game/

Comment: You ignored the several comments telling you that setInterval needs an interval value in milliseconds  as second parameter. Also you cannot clearInterval if you want the score to update.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it, adding relevant (OR REMOVING irrelevant) HTML JS and CSS to have a [mcve] we already asked for in previous question.

Comment: The problem is you are updating the score every 10ms as long as the player is jumping. You need a flag that resets if Mario lands on the ground. Before that the score should not increment more than 1 even if called multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many functions. You want this

```js
const pontos = document.getElementById('score');
let pontuacao = 0;

function updated() {
  pontos.innerHTML = "score: " + pontuacao++;
}

const loopGame = setInterval(() => {
  // if (pipePosition <= 0 && marioPosition >= 0) { 
  //   tocaMarioCoin();

      updated(); // call only when Mario does something that earns a point

  // }
  // else { clearInterval(loopGame);   pontos.innerHTML = "Game over"; }

}, 100);
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div id="score"></div>
</div>
```